# Storing complete git repository in parent git repository

Tags: git

When trying to add a git repository to a parent git repository git either ignores the `.git` folder completely or wants to add the repository as a submodule. Instead if want to store the complete repository with the meta information in `.git` inside the parent repository. This should serve as a backup in case the repository disappears or there is a force push I don't agree with.

EDIT to clarify my needs: I have lots of those sub repositories and there is a chance that the upstream remote disappears because some of those sub repositories are orphaned for a long time on the other hand I want to keep the `.git` metadata to be able to merge new upstream changes with my personal changes in some of the sub repositories. When using submodules in case a submodules remote disappears you are no longer able to recursively clone the parent repository.

Comment: This is not a sensible thing to do. You effectively want to version control your version control, which is completely unnecessary. Every single Git command is reversible, and each clone is a complete copy already.

Comment: If upstream disappears every machine with latest copy has all the history (unless they did shallow clones. then they'll only have latest history). So you can just upload your copy to the upstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want to track same meta in two places, but git subtree might work for you.

[Below example comes from this blog post](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree)

```
git subtree add --prefix .vim/bundle/tpope-vim-surround https://bitbucket.org/vim-plugins-mirror/vim-surround.git master --squash
```

> The common practice is to not store the entire history of the subproject in your main repository, but If you want to preserve it just omit the –squash flag.